# iTextSharp formatting retained on pdf

Tags: html, pdf

I'm trying to convert html to pdf using iTextSharp.dll. Although on the output pdf document, it renders the html markup without formatted text. Please tell me what am I missing.

```
        Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 50, 50, 25, 25);
        var textInput = Label1.Text;
        try
        {
        var output = new MemoryStream();
        var writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, output);
        pdfDoc.Open();
        var logo = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(Server.MapPath("~/Image/image1.jpg"));
        logo.SetAbsolutePosition(400, 750);
        pdfDoc.Add(logo);
        Paragraph para = new Paragraph(textInput);
        para.Alignment = Element.PARAGRAPH;
        pdfDoc.Add(para);
        Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", string.Format("attachment;filename=Doc-{0}.pdf", TextBox3.Text));
        Response.BinaryWrite(output.ToArray());
        }
        catch (DocumentException dex)
        {
            throw (dex);
        }
        catch (IOException ioex)
        {
            throw (ioex);
        }
        finally
        {
            pdfDoc.Close();
        }
    }
```

I would greatly appreciate any help.

Comment: So... what I need is the pdf file not to display markup for eg; as <p>this is a pdf document</p> and such? The html tags are preserved on the output file.

Comment: They are preserved because you don't parse them. Google for the itext xmlworker. Furthermore you close the document after extracting the generated PDF bytes. As the PDF is finalized during that `close`, you'll likely return invalid PDFs to your caller.